# How do you 'post' a json string from corona sdk app to php server?

Tags: php, json, lua, coronasdk

I am developing an app using Corona SDK.  I am trying to 'post' information to a mySQL server and I am passing null values.  I know that the variable on the app side contains a value in the form of a json string.  I also know that the php works to enter information into the database.  What I am not sure of is how to get the json string to be decoded by php so that the information can be sent to the database.  I'm fairly certain that I am missing code on the php side, but I can't find any examples using Corona SDK to PHP to find out what.  I will place the code for both the lua and the php below.  Any assistance would be extremely helpful.

---

### Lua CODE

```
local json = require "json"

print ("test")

sendInfo = {["asked"] = 5, ["correct"] = 3, ["wrong"] = 2}

print(sendInfo)

local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!" )
    else
        print( "RESPONSE: "..event.response )
    end
end

local headers = {
    ["Content-Tpe"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    ["Accept-Language"] = "en-US",
}

local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = json.encode( sendInfo )

print( "params.body: "..params.body )

network.request( httpAddr, "POST", networkListener, params)
```

---

### PHP CODE

```
$data = array( 'asked' => $_POST['asked'], 'correct' => $_POST['correct'], 'wrong' =>         $_POST['wrong']);
$jsondata = json_encode($data);
echo$jsondata;

$json = json_decode($sendInfo, true);
var_dump($json);

echo  "<br />" . $json["asked"];
$a = $json["asked"];
$c = $json["correct"];
$w = $json["wrong"];
$d = date("Y-m-d");
$t = date("H:i:s");

echo  "<br />Total Questions Asked: " . $a;
echo  "<br />Total Questions Correct: " . $c;
echo  "<br />Total Questions Wrong: " . $w;
echo  "<br />Today's Date is : " . $d . " and the time is: " . $t . "<br />";
try
{
    $pdo = new
    PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=test',$username,$password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

    }
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
}

echo 'Successful Connection to Server';

$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO results (date, time, asked, correct, wrong) VALUES ('$d', '$t', '$a', '$c', '$w')");

?>
```

Comment: json is json. if your lua code is sending it properly to php, then you get it from $_POST or php://input, whever it is, and run it through `json_decode()`.

Comment: Based on what I'm posting in the lua code, what should I be having the php code look for? Because the encoded json string is being added to the params array, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: never dealt with lusa, but looks like you're just stuffing the raw json string into the response body. since it's not a `name=value` type construct, PHP won't see anything to put into $_POST, meaning you'll have to try reading it from php://input, e.g. `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Perhaps I'm not quite understanding how a 'post' command works.  My understanding is that the 'post' command sends the information from the client to the php file on the server.  If that's the case, then I am sending the table, params, from the client (lua) to the server (php).  The 'file_get_contents('php://input') should receive whatever is being sent to the server, correct??? I should, theoretically, be able to echo or var_dump...depending on the format of the information sent from the client.

Comment: yes, post sends data to the client. but php requires that data to be in `key=value&key2=value2&etc...` format for it to build $_POST. no key=value, you don't get anything in $_POST, and have to read the raw post data via php://input.

Comment: So do I echo or var_dump $data = file_get_contents('php://input')?

Answer (score 0):

If you will send a JSON, you need to change the content-type to `["Content-Type"] = "application/json"`